I need to size this logo to 20" width and add bleed and crop marks. Please help!
I need to know how to resize the logo below to 20" width and then add crop and bleed marks so that I can send this to a printshop to be printed and cut out at the specified size.


Do you have access to the vector version of this ? If it is a raster version then what is it's size and resolution ? This will all make a difference in your options. What software do you have access to ? Please add some more information to get accurate help.

I have the .ai file and access to the full Adobe suite

This depends on your print shop, and your print shop should be contacted for specific instructions, because all of them will have their own specific requirements for such a print job.
They can also request specific color settings applied to the vector file.
The easy solution and this is common with some print shops, you can just send them the vector file you mentioned you have, and they'll know what to do for a 20" print and they can probably do that for you, as it only probably takes them 2 minutes of work. If its a print shop that does these commercial signs regularly, chances are they do this type of work multiple times in a day.
If you need to do this yourself, open the vector file you mentioned in Illustrator, make the artboard size 20" and make the logo 20" and then send them the resulting vector file.
Whether you do the processing or they do it, either way they will need to get a vector file from you.
